# Passing ref to XML::XPath object to a sub in Perl doesn't work as expected

Tags: xml, perl, xpath, pass-by-reference, cpan

So I have some perl code that goes something like:

```
use strict;
use XML::XPath;

# $xml is an xml string read from file
my $returnVal = mySubA($xml);

#... some more code ...

# sub definition
sub mySubA {
  my ($xml) = @_;
  my $xp = XML::XPath->new(xml => $xml);

  my @fields = $xp->find('/elA/elB/elC')->get_nodelist;

  # foreach elC, get desired info...
  foreach my $field (@fields) {
    $xp = XML:XPath->new(context => $field);
    my $info1 = $xp->find('/info1')->string_value;
    print "\nINFO1: $info1";

    my $info2 = $xp->find('/info2')->string_value;
  }
  # do some stuff....
  return $returnVal;
}
```

This works fine and prints out INFO1: value... .  I'm now changing the code, and am trying to get information from another section of the xml, and so I've written a different sub for it.  To avoid parsing the same xml twice, I'm trying to write my code only using 1 xpath object (see [XPath new in perl docs](http://search.cpan.org/~msergeant/XML-XPath-1.13/XPath.pm#new())).

So now my code is something like....

```
use strict;
use XML::XPath;

# $xml is an xml string read from file
my $xp = XML::XPath->new(xml => $xml);
my $returnValA = mySubA($xp);
my $returnValB = mySubB($xp); 

#... some more code ...

# sub definition
sub mySubA {
  my ($xp) = @_;

  my @fields = $xp->find('/elA/elB/elC')->get_nodelist;

  # foreach elC, get desired info...
  foreach my $field (@fields) {
    $xp = XML:XPath->new(context => $field);
    my $info1 = $xp->find('/info1')->string_value;
    print "\nINFO1: $info1";

    my $info2 = $xp->find('/info2')->string_value;
  }
  # do some stuff...
  return $returnVal;
}

sub mySubB {
  my ($xp) = @_;
  # do some stuff....
  return $returnVal;
}
```

So, basically, I'm passing the ref to the xpath object into mySubA instead of creating it within mySubA.  The problem is that no values are being found, even though I'm pretty sure the xpath expression is resolving something because the loop iterates about 10 times.  I'm new to perl, so I might be missing something here, but the thing that is confusing for me is that the second method - mySubB - is working fine; kind of blowing away my first suspicion that there is a problem with passing the xpath object into the sub (as in, I'm not dereferencing/referencing the xpath object as I should be).

I don't know if its relevant or not, but the xml I'm working with doesn't contain any namespaces or attributes.

Comment: re-reading your question.... what happens if you replace my $info1 = $xp->find('/info1'); by my $info1 = $xp->findvalue('/info1'); (replace find by findvalue)?

Comment: good catch; but here is what I had in my program that I failed to include in my example:

my $info1 = xp->find('/info1')->string_value;

I'll update the example with what you've pointed out; but I'll also try using the findvalue - just for experimentation's sake.

Comment: "xp->find('/info1')->string_value;" has the same results as xp->findvalue('/info1');  So basically, I'm still in the same place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are going to extract more than just one child element, I would use a direct XPath expression:

```
/elA/elB/elC/info1
```

If this is not your case, then you should use the XPath expression to select the parents `elC` and after that **use simple DOM method to get the children**.

If you are going to use some complex selecting from the `elC` element, then there should be for you in your XPath engine some method taking an expression and a context node. But do note that if `elC` is the context node, then you should use a **relative XPath** like `info1` instead of an **absolute XPath** like `/info1`

Comment: @Alejandro, yes, I am extracting more than one element.  My example didn't clearly show that and I will update it to do so, but the xml structure of the relevant information is:

<elA>
  <elB>
    <elC>
      <info1></info1>
      <info2></info2>
    </elC>
  </elB>
</elA>

Comment: @Alejandro - you're right.  Using the relative path did work and fix my second example.  But, there is something I am still very confused about.  Why does my first example work and my second one not?  Even though your solution does fix my second example, it doesn't explain why using the absolute path /info1 in my first example works.

Comment: @Dave: That could be because `XML::XPath` constructor is taking the node argument as a new **document node** instead of a **context node**...

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure of the line `$xp = XML:XPath->new(context => $field);`? I have never used XML::XPath this way, even though it's in the docs. Maybe try getting rid of that line and replacing the following by `my $info1 = $xp->find('/info1', $field);`, which should do the same thing.

In any case, if you are not tied to XML::XPath, you should probably try using XML::LibXML instead. It is better maintained, faster, more powerful... you name it. It is also very similar to XML::Xpath in that it implements the DOM and XPath, so the code would be very similar.

Comment: haha - I'm already elbow deep into a rewrite using XML::LibXML.  I was planning on doing that anyway; I just asked because I was curious.  I still have unchanged copy of the XML::XPath version, so I'll give your recommendation a try and post back.

Comment: Using that $xp->find('/info1', $field); as opposed to $xp = XML:XPath->new(context => $field); doesn't appear to work.  Even when I went back and tried on my first example :/

Comment: @Dave: That's because what I was telling you about relative and absolute path. Do really read my whole answer...

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new `XML::XPath` object each time through your loop, when you do

```
$xp = XML:XPath->new(context => $field);
```

This object doesn't have any XML in it to work on. You're also temporarily hiding the `$xp` that you got an an argument to your function until the end of the block -- you would have gotten a warning about this if you had `use warnings` turned on.

You can set an XPath context in the `find` method, so something like this should work:

```
foreach my $field ( @fields ) { 
    my $info1 = $xp->find('/info1', $field);
    print "\nINFO1: $info1";
}
```

Comment: actually the docs state that you can do that, see http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-XPath/XPath.pm#new() The way it's done in the question is a bit dodgy, as $xp gets overwritten with each loop, but it could work (except that it doesn't ;--)

Comment: see my second comment on mirod's answer.  I did give what you suggested a try, and it doesn't appear to be working.  Also, the "$xp = XML:XPath->new(context => $field);" does work in the first example that I provided.

Comment: also, I do have "use warnings;" at the top of my script.  I do get a warning, but it seems unrelated to what you're talking about as far as I can tell.  "main::PrintUsage() called too early to check prototype at fia_qa_parse_output_xml.pl line 17."  In my actual script, I have a PrintUsage method defined.